# What is a 4-8 mesh?

Tags: terminology, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, machine-learning

A paper I'm reading uses this classification for a mesh, but I'm not sure what the numbers 4 and 8 signify. Could someone clarify? [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6IkT.jpg) from [the paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=adaptive%204-8&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,29&as_sdtp=on) of a 4-8 mesh.

Comment: google seems to give out this good result http://mrl.nyu.edu/~dzorin/papers/velho20014s.pdf

Comment: check out this page, I hope you find it useful
http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/stockroom-reagents/learning-center/technical-library/particle-size-conversion.html

Answer (score 3):

*This is a CW answer intended to remove this question from the unanswered queue.*

---

Bhargav provided an answer in the comments in the form of a link which Phineas seemed to find conclusive: [this link](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~dzorin/papers/velho20014s.pdf).